# Made of/with/from/out of

Tags: word-choice

I know there have been discussions about the difference between them before too. But I wrote a summary on how they are usually used based on different explanations and exceptions. Is it written correctly?

"Made from" is used to refer to something which is made of individual components.
"Made of" is used to refer to the material with which something has been manufactured.
"Made out of" can be used for both "made from"and "made of" and "made up".
Only "made up" and "made from" only these two are used in the sense of composed of several components.
When talking about food all these forms can be used.
"This chocolate vegan cake is made with/made from/made of/made up/made out of ... the list of ingredients."

But is "made with" used only when talking about food?

Comment: FYI: The phrase is "made up of," not just "made up." "Made up" has other meanings that have nothing to do with what you're talking about, so the "of" is key.

Comment: Thank you. But is the rest written correctly and is "made with" used to talk about food only?